# AWS key pair storage

Tags: amazon-web-services

We are planning to have a terminal server setup to access all the AWS instances including EMR etc. So we have planned to store key pair of all the instances on terminal server. Is this a best practice ? If not then how to access the AWS infra

Comment: Are you planning to store EC2 pem files on that terminal server/

Answer (score 0):

That should work. It sounds like the [Bastion Server](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx2ZWDW1QA6D62Y/Controlling-network-access-to-EC2-instances-using-a-bastion-server) concept. It gives you a single exposed server to harden against attacks, which generally simplifies your infrastructure security.